# Complex mathematical proof

Tags: proof-writing, induction

We have alphabet consisting of two chars $\{ 0, 1 \}$ and over this alphabet we have language defined by following rules:

1. There are no words of length $1$
2. Words of length $2$ are only "$10$" and "$00$"
3. Every other combination of chars of length $n$ where $n > 2$ is considered a word when "$1$" are left where they're supposed to be and "$0$" are replaced with another arbitrary word of length smaller than $n$

How do I show that for every positive $n$ is the number of words of length $n$ equal to: $$\frac{2^n+2*(-1)^n}{3}$$

```
Example

  n = 1 -> { }
  n = 2 -> { 10, 00 }
  n = 3 -> { 110, 100 }
  n = 4 -> { 1010, 1000, 0010, 0000, 1110, 1100 }
  ...
```

Comment: Rule 3 doesn't make sense.

Comment: This is https://oeis.org/A078008 if the different formulations of the sequence given there sparks anyone's imagination

Comment: @DonThousand So the six terms of n=4 are like this: Take the 0's from 00 and replace each with the two-letter words and you get 10+10, 10+00, 00+10, and 00+00.  Take the one 0 from 110 and replace the zero with the two-letter words and you get 11+10 and 11+00.

Comment: @DonThousand Having said that, I would only try to create the 10 words of length 5 if someone's life depended on it.  ^_^

Comment: @MatthewDaly Why isn't $000$ a possibility for $n=3$/

Comment: @DonThousand If you start from 10, you get 110 and 100. If you start from 00, you need to replace both zeros, so you get a 4 digit word

Comment: @Andrei Ah you must replace ALL of the $0$s. Got it.

Comment: @DonThousand Right, and those became four of the 4-letter words.